# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'customer' (errno: -1)

Tags: mysql

I ran update query on the customer table and the table got crashed. I am unable to delete or create new table.

```
create table customer(name varchar(10));
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'customer' (errno: -1)
```

Comment: Probably try restating the MySQL service.